# Create an instance of a class inside the same class and use the same class as parameter

Tags: python, class, oop, breadth-first-search

I have the following class:

```
class state(list):
    def __init__(self,parent = None, path = None, *args):
        list.__init__(self, *args)
        self.n = len(self)
        self.parent = parent
        self.path = path

    def neighbors(self):
        lista = []
        if self.__hasUp():
            lista.append(state(Self,'Up',self.__swap(self.index(0),self.index(0) - 3))))            
        if self.__hasDown():
            lista.append(state(Self,'Down',self.__swap(self.index(0),self.index(0) + 3))))
        if self.__hasLeft():
            lista.append(state(Self,'Left',self.__swap(self.index(0),self.index(0) - 1))))
        if self.__hasRight():
            lista.append(state(Self,'Right',self.__swap(self.index(0),self.index(0) + 1))))

        return lista
```

I normally create an instance of the class as follow:

```
inicial = state(None,None,[1,2,5,3,4,0,6,7,8])
```

I need to do the followin (I think if I put the whole context of what I am doing, it will be missleading):

```
anotherList = []
for neighbor in inicial.neighbors():
    anotherList.append(neighbor)
```

I just want to have a list with few extra attributes and methods. The problem is I need this class to create istances of itself with the object that is creating them as a parameter in the neighbors method. I have testet all methods referenced in the code and they work as expected, but I just think they are not need for this question and they will make it a really long question.

I have also checked this [Declaring a class with an instance of it inside in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10823556/declaring-a-class-with-an-instance-of-it-inside-in-python), [Create static instances of a class inside said class in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2546608/create-static-instances-of-a-class-inside-said-class-in-python) and this [Class constructor able to init with an instance of the same class object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33127950/class-constructor-able-to-init-with-an-instance-of-the-same-class-object). However, I do not understand it yet :(

I am quite an amateur,so if you have any suggestions, they are all welcome ;)

Comment: You might want to subclass `UserList` from `collections`, while this is no solution to your OP, I considered it important to note.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am sorry..I tried and it turns out it is very straightforward. It was simply a mistake from the beggining. I leave the answer here in case someone needs it, but if you suggest I delete it (is it possible?) I'will do it.

```
class test(list):
    def __init__(self,pa, name, *args):
        list.__init__(self, *args)
        self.name = name
        self.par = pa

    def create(self):
        lista = []
        lista.append(test(self,'a',[0,1]))
        lista.append(test(self,'b',[0,2]))
        return lista
```

Best regards,