# How to do function overloading?

Tags: python, constructor, overloading

How do you overload functions in Python? I know about default arguments, but what if you want one version of a function to take one type and another version to take a different type. In some cases it is easier to write two different functions with different names like *from_int* and *from_str*, but this is not always viable in certain cases like the *_init_* method.

A simple example:

```
class Point:
    def __init__(self, x, y):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y

    def __init__(self, point):
        self.x = point.x
        self.y = point.y
```

Obviously this would not work since there are two definitions of the same function.

I have looked at other questions on SO about overloading functions, but most of them refer to using default arguments and I don't think that would work in this case especially if I wanted to use default arguments for a different purpose. Lets say I wanted the first constructor to set *x* and *y* to zero if nothing was given: *_init_(x=0,y=0)*

This would become even more problematic if I wanted a third version of *_init_* to init both *x* and *y* from one scalar value:

```
def __init__(self, n):
    self.x = n
    self.y = n
```

In C++ these constructors would be trivial to implement but I do not know of a clean way to do it in python.

I thought about doing this but it does not seem very clean to call:

```
class Point:
    def __init__(self, x=0, y=0):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y

    @staticmethod
    def from_pair(x, y):
        return Point(x, y)

    @staticmethod
    def from_single(n):
        return Point(n, n)

    @staticmethod
    def from_point(point):
        return Point(point.x, point.y)
```

Comment: You might want to look into classmethods: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19305296/multiple-constructors-in-python-using-inheritance

Comment: I already know about the whole classmethod/staticmethod semi-solution. I have it in my answer as an example of what I don't want. The link Duikboot attached and the link to the "duplicate" question do not answer my question.