# Idiomatic way to default mutable arguments

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x

In python, a well known edge case occurs if you directly make a mutable type a default argument:

```
def foo(x=[]): return x
y = foo()
y.append(1)
print foo()
```

The usual work-around is to default the argument to `None` and then set it in the body. However, there's 3 different ways to do this, 2 of which are basically the same but the third is quite different.

```
def foo(x=None):
    if x is None:
        x = []
    return x
```

This is what I usually see.

```
def foo(x=None):
    x = [] if x is None else x
    return x
```

Identical semantically. A line shorter, but some people complain that python's ternary is unnatural because it doesn't start with the conditional and recommend avoiding it.

```
def foo(x=None):
    x = x or []
```

This is the shortest. I only learned about this madness today. I know lisp so this is probably less surprising to me than some python programmers, but I never thought this would work in python. This behavior is different; if you pass something that is not `None` but evaluates false (like `False`) it will not override the default. It can't be used if the default doesn't evaluate false, so if you have a non-empty list or dict default it cannot be used. But empty lists/dicts are (in my experience) 99% of the cases of interest.

Any thoughts on which is the most pythonic? I realize there is an element of opinion here, but I'm hoping someone can give a good example or reasoning as to what is considered the most idiomatic. Compared to most communities python tends to strongly encourage people to do things a certain way so I'm hoping this question and its answers will be useful even if it's not totally black and white.

Comment: in general using `x=A or B` to create a ternary statement in python is frowned upon and considered poor practice... that said go for it ... but I would **argue** that the python ternary statement (option B) is the most pythonic... but im pretty sure this question is going to get closed as its not really appropriate for SO (SO hates "opinions" and prefers "facts")

Comment: Also, if you expecting a mutable object (for e.g. a `list`), why not `x = x if x else []` ? It's little bit shorter, but there's a "corner" case, if `x` is a `True` boolean.

Comment: "but the third *id*". **is**?

Comment: Explicitly checking for None >> checking for any falsey values

Comment: I have another for you: `def foo(**kwargs): return kwargs.get('x', [])`.

Comment: It's also worth noting that the third option behaves differently in certain aspects; if you pass in `x=[]`, the third option will actually create a _new_ list and return that, while the other options will return exactly the list you passed in. This matters if you want to use the same list object in multiple places, sharing its contents.

Comment: @marcelm I don't understand what you mean by another. You mean another edge case,or another way to solve the problem? I think the latter. But `**kwargs` behaves totally differently to the caller, it allows passing in random arguments. Clearly `**kwargs` should not be used unless you are forwarding to another function or really intend to consume all of it. Thanks for your note about explicitly passing in `x=[]`, I hadn't thought of that.

Comment: @NirFriedman Yes, I meant another way to solve the problem. I disagree it behaves "totally different". Yes, there are differences, but that also applies to your third option (pass in `0`, for example). I also disagree with _having_ to consume all of `kwargs`. You could always change `.get()` to `.pop()` and check if anything remains in `kwargs`, if you want to check for unexpected keyword arguments.

Comment: The second one isn't even "a line shorter" if you're willing to go with a single line version of the first, with `if x is None: x = []`.

Answer (score 2):

I'd go with #1 because it's simpler; its "else" branch is implied. It is harder to misinterpret it.

I'd *not* go with #3 in this particular case: `bool(x)` is equally false for `None`, `[]`, `{}`, `()`, `0` and a few other things. If by mistake I pass a `0` into a function that expects a list, it's better if the function fails fast, instead of mistaking the zero for an empty list!

In other cases `c and x else y` could be a convenient ternary operator, but you have to control the type of `c`; it's easier when it's a local variable and not a function parameter.

If you often find yourself substituting a value for `None`, white a function for that. Consider something like `x = replace_none(x, [])`.

Answer (score 1):

I'd say the first way is best in the general case. The first and second way are functionally equivalent, but the first will be easier to read for newcomers.

```
def foo(x=None):
    if x is None:
        x = []
    return x
```

The `x or []` trick can only be used if:

- The argument will not be mutated (since you replace an empty collection by a new one).
- You do not care between different falsy values of the argument (because you lose any difference between `[]`, `{}`, `None`, my-special-class-with-`__bool__`).
- You think anyone reading your code knows how it works (or wants to go figure it out).

Ass a side note, the `or` trick can be used if the default evaluates to true: `x or [1]` will still be `[1]` if `x` is falsy. But you won't be able to use `[]` as argument, as it will be replaced by `[1]`.

Comment: "the `or` trick can be used if the default evaluates to true: `x or [1]` will still be `[1]` if `x` is falsy" This breaks when you pass in `[]` as an argument, as `x` will be falsely changed to `[1]`. I think that's what OP meant.

Comment: @flornquake Yes, you are correct, maybe I should have spelled it out.

Comment: I'd say that's not related to the default being true; `x or []` or `x or [1]` both replace `0` by a list, which is perhaps equally undesirable. But I understand your intention now.

Comment: @Mark it is related in the sense that usually in python you expect a particular interface. Usually passing an integer for a list would be bad regardless. So if the default is a dict, let's say in the common case we restrict ourselves to dict like types, which in practice behave very similarly to dicts (e.g. default and ordered dicts). But most truthy types in python have only one value that is false. If that is your default, then you can't have an issue when passing the right type. But if a True value (e.g. non-empty dict) is default, you cannot pass empty dict explicitly, which is a problem.

Comment: Ok fair enough, I've updated the last part a bit, feel free to make further edits