# How do I use classes for data manipulation in Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, file, class, oop

I have some experience in Python and want to manipulate some data files using classes, mostly to gain experience in OOP. Here is the scenario: for each sample that we test (e.g., sample_1), the tool generates a text data file (e.g., sample_1_file) with the following structure (you can see the file has different data sections):

```
test_type_I, meta_data_I
{data_I = n1 rows x m1 columns}

test_type_II, meta_data_II
{data_II = n2 rows x m2 columns}

test_type_III
{data_III = n3 rows x m3 columns}
.
.
and so on
```

What I hope to achieve is to be able to access the test_type, meta_data, and data, for each data section, and then manipulate the data however I want. For example, say I create an object like

```
sample_1 = myClass(sample_1_file)
```

then I want to be able to access different sections of the data file:

```
sample_1.meta_data_I
plot(sample_1.data_I['x'],sample_1.data_I['y'])
print(sample_1.data_I)
and so on
```

I have read about classes, and have seen some youtube videos, typical employee class and such. However, in my case, here are my questions:

```
1. What does my __init__ method take as input? 
2. What am I initializing?
3. What would be my typical methods?
4. What are the data for my class
```

I can do what I want with simple functions in Python (and pandas), but I really want to gain experience in classes and want to apply it to something that is relevant to my work. I found this: [How to overload __init__ method based on argument type?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/141545/how-to-overload-init-method-based-on-argument-type)
which has some relevance, but the answer uses advanced concepts that I am not familiar with.

Answer (score 1):

The simplest version of a class would look something like this:

```
class SampleResult():
    def __init__(self, sample_number, sample_dataframe):
        self.number = sample_number
        self.data = sample_dataframe
```

You would then instantiate this class with the following:

`result1 = SampleResult(1, sample1_dataframe)`

You would access the data, for example, with:

`result1.data['x']`

In this code, you are instantiating an instance of a `SampleResult` object. You can set the `__init__` method to take any parameters you like - but every method must accept at least one parameter called `self` (the name "self" is simply a convention, but a very strong convention).

Your methods and data are entirely up to you - it depends on what you want to do!