# Class Attributes VALUES to a list

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have a simple python class that consists of some attributes and some methods.What i need is to make a list out of the class attributes ( only ! )

```
Class A():
    def __init__(self, a=50, b="ship"):
        a = a
        b = b

    def method1():
         .....
```

I want to have a list  :

[50, "ship"]

Comment: use the `__str__` ? https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__str__  - or do you need it for other things then output? if so, edit your questions pls.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
def asList(self):
    return [a,b,....] # will create a new list on each call
```

Unless you also create an `__init__(...)` or factory methods or something alike for your class that decomposes this list you wont be able to create a new object back from the list.

See [how-to-overload-init-method-based-on-argument-type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/141545/how-to-overload-init-method-based-on-argument-type)

Answer (score 3):

Another solution, possibly more generic, is:

```
def asList(self):
    [value for value in self.__dict__.values()]
```

Full example with correct syntax:

```
class A:
    def __init__(self, a=50, b="ship"):
        self.a = a
        self.b = b

    def as_list(self):
        return [value for value in self.__dict__.values()]

a = A()
print a.as_list()
```

output:

```
[50, 'ship']
```