# Python Type Hinting: type hinting in the class definition itself

Tags: python, class, type-hinting

```
class Session:
    

    @staticmethod
    def load_from_json(json_path:str) -> Session:
        pass
```

Above throws a `NameError: name 'Session' is not defined`.
Is using itself for the type hint in its definition impossible?

Comment: Is the function supposed to be returning an instance of the class?

Comment: @Boskosnitch Yes. It is supposed to read a json file and create an instance of `Session `using the parameters specified in the json file.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to overload \_\_init\_\_ method based on argument type?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/141545/how-to-overload-init-method-based-on-argument-type)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use:

```
def ... -> 'Session':
```

Session is not defined when you use it, so you must use a string (Python 3.8).

Comment: Alternatively: `from __future__ import annotations`  for python3.7+. Starting with python 3.10 it should just work.

Answer (score 0):

1. Class constructors are defined with **init**(self,..)
2. **init** methods should always have 'None' as the return type if you must include a return type in the type hints.
3. The method posted is not a class method, as it does not alter any class attributes or behaviors.

To construct the class instance:

```
class Session:
    def __init__(self,json_path: str) -> None:
        do stuff...
```

Feel free to correct me if I'm misunderstanding anything

Comment: I already defined a `init`. I needed another method to init using parameters in the file. Sorry for not including full code