# Initializing python object using different object types as arguments

Tags: python, constructor, initialization, class-method

I'v read [how to overload...](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/141545/how-to-overload-init-method-based-on-argument-type) and [multiple constructors in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/682504/what-is-a-clean-pythonic-way-to-have-multiple-constructors-in-python) and a few more on this topic, however I'm looking for something more specific.
I'm given a list of `Content` objects and a list of `Data` objects:

```
class Content:
    def __init__(self):
        self._title = 'movie title'
        self._url = 'http://movie-url'

    @property
    def title(self):
        return self._title

    @property
    def url(self):
        return self._url


class Data:
    def __init__(self):
        self._title = 'movie title'
        self._year = 2021
        self._rating = 7.6

    @property
    def title(self):
        return self._title

    @property
    def year(self):
        return self._year

    @property
    def rating(self):
        return self._rating
```

I want to match each `Content` with it's corresponding `Data` by the title property and combine everything under one class `Movie`, by passing one of the other objects to `Movie`'s init argument:

```
movie_content = Movie(Content())
movie_data = Movie(Data())
```

From what I'v read so far my options are:

- Default arguments: Doesn't seem to fit here (correct me if I'm wrong) since I want to pass only one argument anyway.
- `*args`: I prefer to avoid passing a long line of arguments (there will be at least 12).
- `@classmethod`: This approach is the most appealing to me, but I'm struggling with the implementation:

```
class Movie:
    def __init__(self, object):
        self.object = object

    @classmethod
    def by_content(cls, content):
        _title = content.title
        _url = content.url

        return cls( # what goes here?)

    @classmethod
    def by_data(cls, data):
        _title = data.title
        _year = data.year
        _rating = data.rating

        return cls( # what goes here?)
```

- Using methods as multi-setters, which I'm currently using (not the most pythonic from my understanding):

```
class Movie:
    def __init__(self):
        self._title = ''
        self._url = ''
        self._year = 0
        self._rating = 0.0

    def by_content(self, content):
        self._title = content.title
        self._url = content.url

    def by_data(self, data):
        self._title = data.title
        self._year = data.year
        self._rating = data.rating
```

Any thoughts or suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: ... are you trying to implement a class which acts as a kind of database/movie manager?

Comment: @cards Data is the object representing a record in the database. content is the object representing the movie itself. to make it easier to loop through the movies and show all the relevant information, I thought constructing the Movie class would be good idea.

Comment: so a movie is described by both content and data which are read from the db, right? so why the movie class does not depends on both? For ex Movie(data, content)

Comment: @cards Only the data is read from the db, but yeah Movie depends on both. my initial thought was the same, I just couldn't find a way to match the 2 objects in less then O(n^2)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `classmethod`s as secondary constructors - where you will use the values from the second parameter in the function to fill out the attributes in your `Movie` class's constructor.

I have made the example using `dataclass`es since that makes the code shorter, with the same functionality. (or more)

```py
from dataclasses import dataclass

@dataclass
class Content:
    title: str
    url: str

@dataclass
class Data:
    title: str
    year: str
    rating: float

@dataclass
class Movie:
    title: str
    year: str
    rating: float
    url: str

    @classmethod
    def by_content(cls, content: Content): return cls(
        title = content.title,
        url = content.url,
        rating = 0,
        year = 0,
    )

    @classmethod
    def by_content(cls, data: Data): return cls(
        title = data.title,
        url = 'https://null.com',
        rating = data.rating,
        year = data.year,
    )
```

Comment: Had to read about dataclass... and it works like a charm, thanks! could you possibly hint how do I convert the the dataclass back to the original? I can't figure this out... edit: it seems I can't upvote due to lack of rep, but I'll come back to this once I have.

Comment: @IdanPerry if you look at the source code of dataclasses (note you can also find the code in a backport to 3.6 [here](https://github.com/ericvsmith/dataclasses/blob/master/dataclasses.py)), you'll note that dataclasses are essentially just the same as regular classes. It just simplifies the logic so that you don't need to manually write out an `__init__` or `__repr__` method, for example. So to convert it back to a normal class, it's very simple; just manually assign the dataclass fields in the `__init__` method in a regular class.

Comment: @rv.kvetch Thanks! I initially defined the `__init__` only inside the body with default values but forgot the arguments. now it made me understand why `dataclass` does the same with less code. :-)